# How do I make my page look good with flex-box and changing window sizes?

Tags: css, flexbox, resize, media-queries

I have been tweaking my CSS to make my page look good on mobile and other sizes of the window. I got it to mostly look good, but the only thing I don't like is when the window is medium sized (for like a tablet) there are 2 boxes on one line and the third on the second. This looks really bad in my opinion. Is it possible when the third box gets pushed to the second line, to make all three into a column and upgrade the size of each box a bit to fill some of the empty space?

I've been looking into flex-grow/shrink and I'm not really understanding them to see if that's what I need. I also know there's a media query thing, but don't really understand that either. Here is my current page which doesn't resize: [www.catherinemeza.com](http://www.catherinemeza.com)

Below is my tweaked code so far: (comments are old code or something I've tried to make stuff resize)

```
body {
    background-color: #e9cffb;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.About {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.Name {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#All {
    height: 500px;
    /* width: 1500px;
    margin: 50px auto; */
    /* border: 5px solid black; */
    /* box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 100%; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#ALL > * {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

#One {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 30%; */
}

/* #One p {
    width: 490px;
    height: 490px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -600px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s;
} */

/* #One:hover p {
    opacity: .6;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
} */

.Two {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 30%; */
}

/* .Two p {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    bottom: -600px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(218, 202, 228);
    background-color: rgb(7, 70, 21);
    border: .5px green solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.Two:hover p {
    opacity: .7;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 175px;
} */

#Three {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 30%; */
}

/* #Three p {
    width: 490px;
    height: 490px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -600px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s;
}

#Three:hover p {
    opacity: .6;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: chartreuse;
} */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided doesn't work for me, but you can solve this using media queries and flexbox. What you want to do is open dev tools so you can see the current width of your page in pixels. Resize your page down to the point you want to change (for your case, when the third box goes into the second row). Create a media query for when the screen is that px or less, which you can then add styles to edit the boxes' width and layout. I included an example below.

Breaking it down, this code is saying that when the screen width is 992px or lower, make #All a column-layout and align the items at the center. Also, change the width of each box to take up 100% of its container. You can edit the styling as you wish but if you have any questions don't be afraid to ask!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #All {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #One, .Two, #Three {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: So it changes at 1550. I used your code and changed 992 to 1550 and it doesn't work at all now. It doesn't resize whatsoever. Do I need to remove some of the other code?

Comment: Can you include the HTML for your css? There may be other code in the css such as the 'flex' which is interfering with the resizing. I can help fiddle with it a bit once you include the code (:

Comment: Here is HTML and CSS: https://codepen.io/CatMeza/pen/YzwYxjE

Comment: Alright I found the issue! The reason the boxes wouldn't stack is because in #All, you set a fixed height of 500px; However, you want to make the height responsive so that the container will expand when the elements stack. To fix this, change "height: 500px" to "min-height: 500px". This makes it so the height will be at least 500px on wider screens, but will automatically increase when necessary.

Comment: I would have to do that with the width, too, right? I just checked on my phone and the 500px is too big.

Comment: Not necessarily, the width is already taken care of in the media query where we set the width to 100%. On mobile and smaller screens it will automatically resize to fit your screen (You can edit the percentage to your liking). I forgot to mention, you should add your media queries at the end of the code. At its current location, your boxes are not yet defined in the CSS so the width change is not rendering. I moved the query to the end of your code and it should work!

Comment: Okay, awesome! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to help! If everything works out fine, don't forget to mark an answer so other users know the issue is resolved (= Happy coding!